# call method of a qt class that is using signal slot

Tags: c++, qt

I want to call a method of a class that is using Qt Signal Slot mechanism.
For example:

```
QJsonObject routerInfo;
class LinksysE3000 : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    LinksysE3000(){
        view = new QWebView;
        view->load(QUrl("http://admin:admin@192.168.1.1"));
        connect(view,       SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),this,SLOT(finishedLoading(bool)));
        //view->show();
    }
    ~LinksysE3000()
    {
        view->close();
    }
    QJsonObject getStatus_RouterDetails(QWebFrame*);
    QJsonObject getAll();
public slots:
    void finishedLoading(bool ok);

private:
    QWebView *view;
};

void LinksysE3000::finishedLoading(bool ok)
{
        mainFrame = view->page()->mainFrame();
        routerInfo = getStatus_RouterDetails(mainFrame);
}
QJsonObject LinksysE3000::getAll()
{
return routerInfo;
}
#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    LinksysE3000 LinksysE3000;
    // LinksysE3000.getAll();
    return app.exec();
}
```

This was the code i used. Here I loaded a webpage and get some data using signal slot mechanism.

Here the Signal **loadFinished** is generated only after complete execution of **main**. How can i call getAll() function?

I want to call that **getAll()** function from main or any other class that is instantiate the class **LinksysE3000**. Is it possible? If not.. Is there any other mechanism to load a webpage and extract field values..?

Can somebody help me here to resolve the issue...?

If i use this code I get nothing:

```
class LinksysE3000 : public QObject{
   Q_OBJECT
    public:
    LinksysE3000(){
        view = new QWebView;
        view->load(QUrl("http://admin:admin@192.168.1.1"));
        //connect(view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),this,SLOT(finishedLoading(bool)));
        //view->show();
    }
     ~LinksysE3000()
   {
        view->close();
   }


   QJsonObject getStatus_RouterDetails(QWebFrame*);
   QJsonObject getAll();
   QWebView *view;
   QWebFrame *mainFrame;
   QString clickedPage;
   public slots:
   void finishedLoading(bool ok);

   private:

   };

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {

   QApplication app(argc, argv);
  LinksysE3000 linksysE3000;
  QThread::sleep(3);
  QWebFrame *frame = linksysE3000.view->page()->mainFrame();
  qDebug()<<frame->toPlainText(); //This returns nothing
  QJsonObject obj = linksysE3000.getStatus_RouterDetails(frame);
  qDebug()<<obj;  //This shulod return key value pairs, but retuns empty values means page not loaded

  return app.exec();

  }
```

Comment: Uh, `LinksysE3000.getAll();`?

Comment: What happens if you toggle the comment? Did you try?

Comment: Ya.. Is that possible..?

Comment: If I toggle the comment it returns QJsonObject with  empty values, because the web page is not loaded(loadFinished signal not generated)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. You can call methods on objects with signals and slots just like every other method. Why didn't you just try it?
You can also call slots like normal class methods (if they are not private).

And btw you really should not name your objects exactly like your class

```
LinksysE3000 LinksysE3000;
```

as you can see in the syntax highlighting, it is exactly as confused as every human reader is and from my own experience I can tell you, doing any automatic renaming or any find & replace action really gets a mess.

Comment: Ok.. the signal generates only after  return app.exec(); in main. Then how can  i call the function..

Comment: Your finishedLoading() slot is executed during the Qt's internal main loop, which is hidden behind `QApplication::exec()`. Therefore your data does not become available before the call to `app.exec()`. You have to design your application in such a way that you do all your application logic with the Qt main loop.

Comment: Do you know how to interact with the Qt main loop?

Comment: There are many ways: You may want to react on signals or events provided by your widgets, timers, network sockets, ...

Comment: This greatly depends on what you want to do in your application. One way could be to move part of your main functions logic into your `finishedLoading()` slot. If you don't have a clue what to do you might want to read at least a basic introduction to Qt programming first.